# Save edits to polygon without altering existing

Tags: qgis, editing

I am trying to edit a single polygon and save it as a new file without altering the original polygon in QGIS 3.4.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In edit mode.

- Edit the polygon.
- Select the polygon using one of selection tools.
- "Right click the layer -> Export -> Save Selected Features As..."
- In "Save Vector Layer As..." window, select a file format and path, then save it.

Now, you can redo the changes on original polygon.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach if you want an intermediate layer:

- select the feature you want to edit and do Ctrl + C to copy feature (or "Edit" > "Copy features")
- do Ctrl + Alt + V (or "Edit" > "Paste features As" > "Temporary Scratch Layer...")
- edit the scratch layer as you want and right click the layer "Make Permanent" to save (shoter version of right click > "Export" > "Save Selected Features As..." when not using scratch layer)

You could also save the layer from the copy with "Edit" > "Paste features As" > "New Vector Layer..." if the output format you want to export is editable in QGIS then edit and desactivate edit mode after your modifications. In this case, you already created the file before.

Shortcuts mentioned may vary depending of the OS (PS: on Linux here FYI)